# How to log a bit mask

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotifications]` which returns a bitmask. How do I `NSLog` the bitmask to understand how the bitmask is composed and which notifications are on/off?

Comment: Well, probably as a hex value.

Comment: Hex won't help much. How does a value like "F4A0" tell you what bits are checked any more than a decimal number like 476 would do?

Comment: (But of course that particular interface only returns zero or one -- not a bit mask.)

Comment: @NickLockwood -- Makes it a lot easier to distinguish the individual bits.

Comment: @NickLockwood - very good answer! I know the question says NSLog - another quick way of getting the binary value is to set a breakpoint on the integer of interest and in the debugger variables view, select the variable and right click, choose "View Value As" and choose binary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to print it as binary value so you get a one or zero for each bit. Here is a question that answers how to log a binary value:

[NSInteger to binary (string) value in 8bit format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920213/nsinteger-to-binary-string-value-in-8bit-format)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log the bits symbolically, it takes some programming:

```
NSLog(@"MASK_A = %s, MASK_B = %s, MASK_C =%s", mask & MASK_A ? "YES" : "NO", mask & MASK_B ? "YES" : "NO", mask & MASK_C ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Or:

```
NSLog(@"mask = ( %s%s%s)", mask & MASK_A ? "MASK_A " : "", mask & MASK_B ? "MASK_B " : "", mask & MASK_C ? "MASK_C " : "");
```