# Converting an NSString to bit value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *strVal= @"BAAA";
```

How do I convert the above string into a bit value? Should I do the byte conversion before this?
Need help on this. I have previously checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920213/nsinteger-to-binary-string-value-in-8bit-format) for integer conversion.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a hex representation of a number? Are you supposed to convert it to the binary representation of unicode? Or what?

Comment: you can use dataUsingEncoding to convert an NSString into an NSData object who's octect stream you can easiyl access. You could convert it into a C style string as well and go from there. But I doubt your question is that simple. What are you really up to? Be a bit more specific please.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you convert the string to UTF-8 first is up to you; it depends what you want.  Internally `NSString` stores characters as UTF-16 (might be UCS-2 actually) using the `unichar` type, so you need to decide whether you want the binary of the internal representation or of some other external encoding.

I expect you want the binary of the UTF-8 encoding, so try this (tested):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BinFuncs : NSObject
+ (NSString *)binaryOfString:(NSString *)str;
@end

@implementation BinFuncs

+ (NSString *)binaryOfString:(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableString *binStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    const char *cstr = [str UTF8String];
    size_t len = strlen(cstr);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        uint8_t c = cstr[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            [binStr appendString:((c & 0x80) ? @"1" : @"0")];
            c <<= 1;
        }
    }
    return binStr;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            NSString *binStr = [BinFuncs binaryOfString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[i]]];
            NSLog(@"%@", binStr);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

$ clang -o binstr binstr.m -framework Foundation
$ ./binstr 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
2013-09-30 09:19:49.674 binstr[58474:707] 01110100011010000110010100100000011100010111010101101001011000110110101100100000011000100111001001101111011101110110111000100000011001100110111101111000001000000110101001110101011011010111000001110011001000000110111101110110011001010111001000100000011101000110100001100101001000000110110001100001011110100111100100100000011001000110111101100111
```